# Flask-wtf formsets

Tags: flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

How can i create formsets like [django forms formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/formsets/) and handle them.
I tryed like this

```py
for header in headers:
    field_form = FieldsForm()
    field_form.xls_field.data = fix
    field_form.xls_name.data = header
    field_forms.append(field_form)
    fix += 1
```

Comment: See [these](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/wtforms/ur84vD5S66Y/-n7NIhcHztUJ) solutions.